# SAS Looping through macro variable and processing the data

Tags: loops, sas

I have a bunch of character variables which I need to sort out from a large dataset. The unwanted variables all have entries that are the same or are all missing (meaning I want to drop these from the dataset before processing the data further). The data sets are very large so this cannot be done manually, and I will be doing it a lot of times so I am trying to create a macro which will do just this. I have created a list macro variable with all character variables using the following code (The data for my part is different but I use the same sort of code):

```
data test;
     input Obs ID Age;
datalines;
1 2 3
2 2 1
3 2 2
4 3 1
5 3 2
6 3 3
7 4 1
8 4 2
run;

proc contents
data = test
noprint
out = test_info(keep=name);
run;

proc sql noprint;
select name into : testvarlist separated by ' ' from test_info;
quit;
```

My idea is then to just use a data step to drop this list of variables from the original dataset. Now, the problem is that I need to loop over each variable, and determine if the observations for that variable are all the same or not. My idea is to create a macro that loops over all variables, and for each variable counts the occurrences of the entries. Since the length of this table is equal to the number of unique entries I know that the variable should be dropped if the table is of length 1. My attempt so far is the following code:

```
%macro ListScanner (org_list);
%local i next_name name_list;
%let name_list = &org_list;
%let i=1;
%do %while (%scan(&name_list, &i) ne );
    %let next_name = %scan(&name_list, &i);
    %put &next_name;    
        proc sql;
            create table char_occurrences as
            select &next_name, count(*) as numberofoccurrences
            from &name_list group by &next_name;    
            select count(*) as countrec from char_occurrences;
        quit;
    %if countrec = 1 %then %do;
        proc sql;
            delete &next_name from &org_list;
        quit;
    %end;
    %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
    %end;
%mend;

%ListScanner(org_list = &testvarlist);
```

Though I get syntax errors, and with my real data I get other kinds of problems with not being able to read the data correctly but I am taking one step at a time. I am thinking that I might overcomplicate things so if anyone has an easier solution or can see what might be wrong to I would be very grateful.

Comment: Don't understand what you tried to do, in your macro program, problem is &name_list in proc sql, &name_list is resolved as variables list, not a dataset.

Comment: You can always roll your own, but there are solutions out there. I suggest the searching the SAS blogs, or Google: "sas rick wicklin missing" . The fastest approach is via IML, the 'easiest' coding approach is PROC FREQ and using the NLEVELS variable as well. It also depends on what is a large file. Less than 10 million records should be fine with the PROC FREQ approach, though it may depend on your memory settings as well.

Comment: You mention character variables but your example is numeric variables. Are the variables character or numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this posted around.
But let's just look at the issues you are having.

First for looping through your space delimited list of names it is easier to let the %do loop increment the index variable for you.  Use the `countw()` function to find the upper bound.

```
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&name_list,%str( )));
  %let next_name = %scan(&name_list,&i,%str( ));
  ...
%end;
```

Second where is your input dataset in your SQL code? Add another parameter to your macro definition.  Where to you want to write the dataset without the empty columns?  So perhaps another parameter.

```
%macro ListScanner (dsname , out, name_list);
%local i next_name sep drop_list ;
```

Third you can use a single query to count all of variables at once. Just use `count( distinct xxxx )`  instead of `group by`.

```
proc sql noprint;
create table counts as 
  select 
  %let sep=;
  %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&name_list,%str( )));
    %let next_name = %scan(&name_list,&i,%str( ));
    &sep. count(distinct &next_name) as &next_name
    %let sep=,;
  %end;
  from &dsname 
;
quit;
```

So this will get a dataset with one observation. You can use PROC TRANSPOSE to turn it into one observation per variable instead.

```
proc transpose data=counts out=counts_tall ;
  var _all_;
run;
```

Now you can just query that table to find the names of the columns with 0 non-missing values.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select _name_ into :drop_list separated by ' '
    from counts_tall
    where col1=0
  ;
quit;
```

Now you can use the new `DROP_LIST` macro variable.

```
data &out ;
  set &dsname ;
  drop &drop_list;
run;
```

So now all that is left is to clean up after your self.

```
proc delete data=counts counts_tall ;
run;
%mend;
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much! Could you elaborate a bit on the sep-part? Why divide using a comma instead of e.g. a space? And what does the delete-step in the end do? I am very new to SAS so I have not really got the hang of proper practices in coding yet.

Comment: In the SQL SELECT statement you separate the variables by commas. The SEP macro variable is just a way to put commas between the variables.  The PROC DELETE step will remove the work tables the macro made, just to clean up.  The save space, but also to avoid possible issues if you call the macro multiple times or wanted to use those names for other tables later in your program.  But you might want to keep one or both formats of the counts dataset if it would be useful for you after the macro finishes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your specific initial question, this is fairly straightforward.  Assuming `&testvarlist` is your macro variable containing the variables you are interested in, and creating some test data in `have`:

```
%let testvarlist=x y z;

data have;
  call streaminit(7);
  do id = 1 to 1e6;
    x = floor(rand('Uniform')*10);
    y = floor(rand('Uniform')*10);
    z = floor(rand('Uniform')*10);
    if x=0 and y=4 and z=7 then call missing(of x y z);
    output;
  end;
run;


data want fordel;
  set have;
  if min(of &testvarlist.) = max(of &testvarlist.)
    and (cmiss(of &testvarlist.)=0 or missing(min(of &testvarlist.)))
  then output fordel;
  else output want;
run;
```

This isn't particularly inefficient, but there are certainly better ways to do this, as referenced in comments.

Comment: Will the Min/Max approach work with character data? I know that works in PROC SQL but I think the Base functions need numeric values.

Comment: @Reeza Yes, you're right; I forgot that it only works with numerics.  Odd that SAS chose to not implement MIN/MAX for character variables, but nonetheless.  I'll leave this up since it may be helpful for people with the same numeric issue.